# Visual Studio immediate window command for Clear All

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, immediate-window

Is there a command to clear the immediate window in Visual Studio?

I hate having to grab the mouse for a right click menu there - would rather just type "cls" or something.

Comment: didn't realise there was a right-click menu!

Answer (score 161, accepted):

To clear the immediate window, you can use `>cls`, which is a predefined [command alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3a0kd3x.aspx) to `>Edit.ClearAll`.

[The MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3a0kd3x.aspx) lists all predefined aliases and you can define your own, too. (For VS 2010 and earlier, [custom aliases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xasxzd71(v=vs.100).aspx) are described in a separate article, though.) Scanning through, there's a whole slew of them, some of which might even have their roots in MS-DOS DEBUG.EXE (specifically `>d`, `>g`, `>p`, `>q`, and >`t` come to mind).

---

Also worth noting as it's only two keys to press: Context menu > Clear All invokes the same command and it can be navigated using keyboard. Therefore in the immediate window, you can press <kbd>Context Menu</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>.

If you don't have a [`context-menu` key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) on your keyboard (you know, the one between <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>), you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> instead.

Comment: i normally use the context key when I'm in the office - but i've been working on a laptop for the past few months from a clients office, and I don't have the context key on it.  It finally bothered me enough to look for a solution...

Comment: The `>` is important. Could not think of a natural way to make it more explicit in the answer. Also, see [Immediate Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) on MSDN for more useful tips.

Answer (score 52):

```
>cls
```

seems to do it for me.

Answer (score 23):

1. Place the mouse cursor in the Immediate Window.
2. Right click on the mouse and select "Clear All".

Answer (score 14):

found it...

">Edit.ClearAll"

or

">cls"

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it at run time:

1. Reference the EnvDTE dlls in your application.
2. Create and then use this function as necessary.

```vb
Public Sub ClearImmediateWindow()
  Try
    Dim vsWindowKindImmediateWindow As String _ 
          = "{ECB7191A-597B-41F5-9843-03A4CF275DDE}"
    Try
      Dim obj As Object = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal._ 
                          GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0")
      If obj IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim DTE2 As EnvDTE80.DTE2 = CType(obj, EnvDTE80.DTE2)
        For Each wndw As EnvDTE.Window In DTE2.Windows
          If wndw.ObjectKind = vsWindowKindImmediateWindow Then
            wndw.Activate()
            DTE2.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ClearAll")
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Catch comEx As COMException
      ' Not running from within the VS IDE?
    Catch ex As Exception
      Throw ex
    End Try
  Catch ex As Exception
    ' Handle this as you desire.
  End Try
End Sub
  End Sub
```

Comment: Not working for me. Error is: *"A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"* while getting object from Marshal.

Comment: My visual studio version is 2012 so I changed `VisualStudio.DTE.10.0` to `VisualStudio.DTE.11.0` and it worked. Also here I found a shorter syntax of same answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16873888/2721611](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16873888/2721611)

Answer (score 1):

For visual studio 2012 I use:

```vb
Public Sub ClearImmediateWindow()
    Dim dte As EnvDTE80.DTE2 = Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0")
    dte.Windows.Item("Immediate Window").Activate() 'Activate Immediate Window  
    dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.SelectAll")
    dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ClearAll")
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dte)
End Sub
```

to automatically clear immediate window from codes(requires to add DTE references to project). If it not works try `VisualStudio.DTE.8.0`, `VisualStudio.DTE.9.0`, `...` according to your visual studio version.

Answer (score 1):

I used the last answer just about verbatim and it works, although I wanted the focus back on where it was. Here's the very slightly improved C# version. I enable it with a configuration switch.

```
#if DEBUG
    if (GetIni("Debug", "ClearImmediateWindow", true)) {
        try {
            var dte = (EnvDTE.DTE) Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0");
            var me  = dte.ActiveWindow;
            dte.Windows.Item("Immediate Window").Activate();
            dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ClearAll");
            me.Activate();
        }
        catch { /* Meh! */ }
#endif
```

Comment: Just a gotcha; if you have more than one instance of VS open, Murphy's law dictates that it will clear the other one and leave you trying to figure out why the F^&$%**! it doesn't work. At least that's what I've been doing for the last 20 minutes.

Comment: And now it works, but I think only if VS is the active window. If another window (for example the  project I'm debugging) is active when this code is executed, I get "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED)".

Comment: You're right. If you're running 2 instances, you'd have to work out a rational way to tell one from the other. I imagine you would have to iterate all the main windows and check for the one with the highest ZOrder. I quit using this some time ago because I came up with a better way. I wrote this because Visual Studio steals Debug message. For all other tools I run them through DbgView (SysInternals). I wrote a back end process that captures them before Visual Studio steals them, and forwards them to DbgView, so I got back to what I wanted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Those who are wondering how to clear immediate window on Visual Studio Mac, just right click inside the window and select the option **Clear**