# Is it possible to programmatically clear the Output Window in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Do you know a way to add some code that, **during debug**, programmatically clear the **Output Window** in Visual Studio?

Or do you know some fast alternative like a key shortcut?

Comment: @mafutrct could be an idea, but I never done it, I have to investigate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the Visual Studio (debug) Output window be programatically cleared?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391473/can-the-visual-studio-debug-output-window-be-programatically-cleared)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Macro:

```
Sub ClearOutputWindow()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ClearOutputWindow")
End Sub
```

Simply assign a hotkey to this.

Edit: [additional possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391473/can-the-visual-studio-debug-output-window-be-programatically-cleared)

Answer (score 1):

To clear the IMMEDIATE window in VS2010

```
    Dim dte = Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0")
    Dim ide As EnvDTE80.DTE2 = dte
    Dim currentActiveWindow = dte.ActiveWindow
    dte.Windows.Item("{ECB7191A-597B-41F5-9843-03A4CF275DDE}").Activate() 'Activate Immediate Window  
    dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.SelectAll")
    dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ClearAll")
    currentActiveWindow.Activate()

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dte)
```

Answer (score 0):

the output window feature is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166236(VS.80).aspx), some guys are talking about how to access the output window [here](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/74149/253168.aspx), so i think you can clear it progamatically.

Comment: the first shows some example how to interact with the output window, but I think I need to create a plugin myself to do it; the second link is based on CodeRush, I will look into it. In the meanwhile if you know a simpler way...

Answer (score 0):

I have changed unreadable `"{ECB7191A-597B-41F5-9843-03A4CF275DDE}"` guid code from *smirkingman's* answer to **`"Immediate Window"`** and it worked as well (also removed unnecessary codes for my own):

```vb
Dim dte As EnvDTE80.DTE2 = Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0")
dte.Windows.Item("Immediate Window").Activate() 'Activate Immediate Window  
dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.SelectAll")
dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ClearAll")
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dte)
```