# How to clear debugger output window Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

For VS 2012, I am not able to clear debugger output window using following [MSDN code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/envdte.outputwindowpane.clear.aspx) ,

Basically I am not able to pass DTE2 object, to `ClearExample`.

```
public void ClearExample(DTE2 dte)
{
    // Retrieve the Output window.
    OutputWindow outputWin = dte.ToolWindows.OutputWindow;

    // Find the "Test Pane" Output window pane; if it doesn't exist, 
    // create it.
    OutputWindowPane pane = null;
    try
    {
        pane = outputWin.OutputWindowPanes.Item("Test Pane");
    }
    catch
    {
        pane = outputWin.OutputWindowPanes.Add("Test Pane");
    }

    // Show the Output window and activate the new pane.
    outputWin.Parent.AutoHides = false;
    outputWin.Parent.Activate();
    pane.Activate();

    // Add a line of text to the new pane.
    pane.OutputString("Some text." + "\r\n");

    if (MessageBox.Show("Clear the Output window pane?", "", 
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        pane.Clear();
}
```

Using other SO links couldn't make it work for VS2012.

[Is it possible to programmatically clear the Ouput Window in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651617/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-clear-the-ouput-window-in-visual-studio)

[Can the Visual Studio (debug) Output window be programatically cleared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391473/can-the-visual-studio-debug-output-window-be-programatically-cleared)

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I implemented it. Note the reference to another question-answer that helped me.

```
'   #region ClearOutputWindow
    /// <summary>
    /// Clear the Output window-pane of Visual Studio.
    /// Note: Causes a 1-second delay.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ClearOutputWindow()
    {
        if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Application.DoEvents();  // This is for Windows.Forms.
        // This delay to get it to work. Unsure why. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391473/can-the-visual-studio-debug-output-window-be-programatically-cleared
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // In VS2008 use EnvDTE80.DTE2
        EnvDTE.DTE ide = (EnvDTE.DTE)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");
        if (ide != null)
        {
            ide.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ClearOutputWindow", "");
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ide);
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

'

Comment: Add reference EnvDTE: for VS10: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\EnvDTE.dll

Comment: On my 64-bit system (Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015) `EnvDTE.dll` was located under the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies`.